# $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \prod_{r=1}^n [1 - \tan^2 \frac{\theta}{2^r} ]$ has a telescopic product.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to evaluate $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \prod\limits_{r=1}^n \left[1 - \tan ^ 2 \frac{\theta}{2^r} \right]$. I can't get the given answer, which is $\frac{\theta}{\tan \theta}$.

What I did was telescope the product. Essentially, a given term $$T_r = \left[1 - \tan ^ 2 \frac{\theta}{2^r} \right] =\frac{\cos \frac{\theta}{2^\left(r - 1\right)}}{\cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2^r}}$$

When the terms are listed out, one cosine in denominator of a given term cancels out with the cosine of the numerator of the next term.

Finally, after all cancellation, what remains is $$\frac{\cos \theta}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2 ^ n}\prod\limits_{r=1}^n \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^r} \right)}$$

I multiplied the numerator and denominator with $2 sin (\theta/2^\left(n\right))$. This causes a chain reaction in the denominator because 2 sin A cos A = sin 2A. The sin multiplies with the first term and carries on the product till the entire product turns into $sin \theta$.

So now I have $$\frac{2 \cos\theta \sin\frac{\theta}{2^\left(n\right)}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2^n}\sin\theta}$$

I have double-checked the calculation and this is the best that I have.

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{2 \cos\theta \sin\frac{\theta}{2^n}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2^n}\sin\theta} $ should be equal to $\theta / \tan \theta$, but I am getting the value $0$. Where have I gone wrong in my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your calculate for $\prod_{r=1}^n \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)$ is wrong. In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\prod_{r=1}^n \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)\\
&=&\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^2}\right)\cdots\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\\
&=&\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^2}\right)\cdots\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cdot2\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}\\
&=&\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^2}\right)\cdots\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-1}}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}\\
&=&\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^2}\right)\cdots\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-2}}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-2}}\right)}{2^2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}\\
&=&\cdots\\
&=&\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{2^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}\\
&=&\frac{\cos \left(\theta\right)}{2^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you! I made a very trivial mistake, then. Incorporating the $2^n$ will introduce an indeterminate form that can be evaluated as a limit.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad help you.

Answer (score 2):

It has a much simpler solution:

note that $1-\tan^2(x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{\tan(2x)}$, hence we have that $$\prod_{r=1}^{n}(1-\tan^2(\frac{\theta}{2^r}))=\prod_{r=1}^{n}\frac{2\tan(\frac{\theta}{2^r})}{\tan(\frac{\theta}{2^{r-1}})}=\frac{2^n\tan(\frac{\theta}{2^n})}{\tan(\theta)}$$ and now it is easy to see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n\tan(\frac{\theta}{2^n})=\lim_{n \to \infty}2^n\cdot \frac{\theta}{2^n}=\theta$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it's simpler. I am not aware of the identity related to tan. How did you arrive at it? I am guessing that proving this identity and then calculating the limit will make it just as lengthy.

Comment: Nevermind, I get it, it's the expansion of tan 2x.